# How to bend chipboard into a cylinder without tearing it apart?

Tags: stationery

I am currently trying to make a cylinder out of chipboard(the cardboard that notebooks are typically made out of). However, whenever I try to bend it, parts of the chipboard start to tear. How do I bend chipboard without tearing it apart?

Comment: If there are techniques to bend this type of material, you might ask on our [Woodworking SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) or [DIY site](http://diy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Cannot see why this is off topic.  Also the cardboard that note books use as a cover are called chip board in the USA and what is chip board in the UK is particle board in the USA so this is not a woodworking topic, DIY perhaps.  Paper and card products are made on a continuous line, they have a 'grain' and trying to bend one way is MUCH harder to get right than in the perpendicular direction, moistening the card stock between two damp blotters for some hours or misting it earlier should also help.

Answer (score 2):

If you mist the cardboard with water and let it get a **little** damp, you should be able to bend it without it breaking apart. Once you have your cylinder formed, let it dry out. Exact time required and amount of water might be a bit tricky as not all cardboard will behave the same way.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken that's also how they bend wood soo that indeed my be a good solution, although dried cardboard never looks quite the same as before it was wet.

Comment: A fabric steamer will work well for this.